# How to display the text of an EditText in a url section in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to display the text of a textfield in a url section in android?
Here is the code

```
final Text q = (Text) findViewById(R.id.q);

   Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/search?q="));
   startActivity(i);
```

i want to use as query this `(Text) findViewById(R.id.q);` . How??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually this.

```
final EditText q = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.q);

Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
    Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + q.getText().toString()));
startActivity(i);
```

Note the use of `EditText`. `Text` is not the correct class you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + q.getText()));
```